# Squash and Stretch ball animation in Java

Tags: animation, java-3d, stretch, squash

So im new to Java programming and i was trying to find an example code of Ball animation in 3D with accurate physics involved.
This is the source:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/3D/AnimationandInteractionaBouncingBall.htm

And here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no J3D in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl$22.run(MasterControl.java:889)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.loadLibraries(MasterControl.java:886)
at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:229)
at BouncingBall.<init>(BouncingBall.java:81)
at BouncingBall.main(BouncingBall.java:140)
```

Answer (score 0):

The native libraries are missing and I fear that you use an obsolete version of Java 3D, please follow [these instructions](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D).